# "Make you feel" vs "makes you feel"

Tags: verb-agreement

> Can you think of any activities that makes you feel out of breath?

I think it should be "make you feel out of breath" but my friend says it should be "makes".

Comment: You're correct. He would be correct if it were _any activity_ (singular).

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, the verb should agree with the noun. So it could be either a plural noun with a plural verb:

> Can you think of any activities that make you feel out of breath?

or a singular noun with a singular verb:

> Can you think of any activity that makes you feel out of breath?